# Excel column name containing '.' converted to '#'

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2013, datatable, oledbdataadapter

I am importing an excel file and trying to get the same into a DataSet. The problem is that if the Column Name contains `.` for example if the column name is `Sr. No.` after import the column name shown in the DataSet is `Sr# No#`.

**The following is the code:**

```
public DataSet ConnectExcel(string filetable)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet(TABLE_NAME);
    string excelConnectionString;
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(filetable);

    if (extension == ".xls")
    {
        excelConnectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES\"", strCSVFilePath);
    }
    else
    {
         excelConnectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;\"", strCSVFilePath);
    }

    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection oleDBCon = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

    try
    {
        if (oleDBCon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            //lblResult.Text = "file is in open state. Please close the file.";
        }
        else
        {
            oleDBCon.Open();
            DataTable Sheets = oleDBCon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            foreach (DataRow dr in Sheets.Rows)
            {
                string sht = dr[2].ToString().Replace("'", "");
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sht + "]", oleDBCon);

                try
                {
                    dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
                    ds.Tables[0].TableName = TABLE_NAME;
                    ds.AcceptChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    dataAdapter.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) //Error
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (oleDBCon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            oleDBCon.Close();
        oleDBCon.Dispose();
    }
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: if it is stable then you can replace them in `DataSet` again?

Comment: you can replace # in datatable column names  by looping through each column

Comment: @satsvelke why need loop each **column**?

Comment: @satsvelke @LeiYang  I am letting the user select a file they want to view, so making checks and replacing a `#` won't work as the column name might actually contain a `#` and I am not just supposed to change it to `.`

Comment: @AdarshRavi you can use `connection.GetSchema("Tables")` to know the real sheet names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options here.

In your original data you can put a `'` before any values you don't want converted.

You can also click on each column in the excel spreadsheet and change its data type from General to whatever format you want.

Your third option is to use `IMEX=1` in your connection string.

```
if (extension == ".xls")
{
    excelConnectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;\"", strCSVFilePath);
}
else
{
     excelConnectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;\"", strCSVFilePath);
}
```

If you still have problems after changing the connection string you are going to have to change `HDR` to `NO` and treat your header column as strings as well. In this case you can replace the Column Names with the data in the first row (The actual Column Names) and then remove the first row from your data table using `ds.Tables[0].Rows.RemoveAt(0);`

Comment: I am letting the user to select which file they want to access and I display that file on a datagridview. So any changes to be made to the file to get the desired output is not feasible. `IMEX=1` didn't help. And changing `HDR` to `No` makes my first column which is my header column to a normal data cell which again is not something I would want.

Comment: You have to pick one or the other. You always have the option of making the header text and removing the first row from your data table with `  dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);`

Comment: @AdarshRavi: Pull column names into separate array, then remove from data table `public ExcelWorksheetHelper(DataTable oSrcData)
    {

        moDT = oSrcData;
        int iNumCols = moDT.Columns.Count;
        string [] masColumnNames = new string[iNumCols];

        for (int i = 0; i < iNumCols; i++)
            masColumnNames[i] = moDT.Rows[0][i].ToString();

        moDT.Rows.RemoveAt(0);

    }`